# jQuery if not '0'

Tags: jquery

```
$(".test").css('cursor','pointer');
<div class="test>0</div>
<div class="test>1,000</div>
```

How do I apply this to the elements that are not 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".test").filter(function() {
   return this.innerHTML != '0';
}).css('cursor','pointer');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WMVb2/1/)**

#### Correction to your HTML

```
<div class="test">0</div>  <!-- missing closing quote-->
<div class="test">1,000</div> <!-- missing closing quote-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If i assume correctly, you want `cursor:pointer` to be applied to div with contents that are not 0. Try using filter like below,

```
$('.test').filter(function () { 
      return $(this).text() != '0'; 
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.test').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() != '0')
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

But the easiest would be to add a different class

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this:

```
if($(".test").text() != '0')
  {

     //Your code here   

  }
```

By using .text() it will get the text from the selector (as you may have imagined)